# libreoffice calc replace spaces with underscores

Tags: regex

Words in my libreoffice calc 3.5 spreadsheet cells are separated by spaces.
In the cells of certain columns i need to replace the spaces between words with underscores.
None of my attempts to make a regular expression command have succeeded.

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? Can't you simple replace every space by `_`? Something like Ctrl+F?

Answer (score 2):

Select the column so it is highlighted.
Edit>Find and Replace
type a space in the Find box
type an underscore in the Replace box
Replace all